# *ngFor is not working with indexes as strings

Tags: angular

So I have an array which is of type that is similar to a map

```
["array":[1,2,3,4],"array2":[1,2,3,4]]
```

when I am trying to *ngFor over them the directive is not working, and it seems like it's not seeing the array.

If i change from that array to this

```
[1:[1,2,3,4],2:[1,2,3,4]]
```

it's working perfectly

Does *ngFor not work with indexes that are strings ?

Comment: Show us your `ngFor` loop code.

Comment: i don't know how to add html code

Comment: @Teodor - After pasting the HTML in the question, select it and execute the "Code Sample" command `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

You should have an array of object literals.

`[{array:[1,2,3,4]},{array2:[1,2,3,4]}]`

The keys are strings, and no need for `"`

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong:

```
["array":[1,2,3,4],"array2":[1,2,3,4]]
```

You can't use string keys with regular arrays.

You can instead use an object:

```
{"array":[1,2,3,4],"array2":[1,2,3,4]}
```

Comment: ok i thought that you could do some sort of mapping but it seems like it has to be as an object

Answer (score 1):

You will need to define your indexes as objects as:

```
let arrays = [
    { 'arr1': [1,2,3,4] },
    { 'arr2': [1,2,3,4] },
    { 'arr3': [1,2,3,4] }
  ];
```